# Load an ASP Website retrieve and redirect a href in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am doing my first add-in Outlook. I want to  load an ASP website in a Form and redirect with the `href` which is in a `<li>` tag. There is no specific id to identify only the value of the `<span>`. See below. Thank's in advance.

```
<li class="rmItem ">
<a class="rmLink rmSelected" style="width: 194px;" href="javascript:Goto('DM_NEW_OBJECT.ASPX?DM_CAT_ID=2171&amp;DM_PARENT_ID=254769&amp;INPUTSELECTION=&amp;DM_OBJECT_ID=0&amp;PACK_ID=0&amp;CASE_ID=0&amp;mode=0&amp;SITE=Default');">
<span class="rmText">Dossier protection</span>
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: With what part do you need help? To retrieve the href or to redirect? And which kind of control is used to do the redirection?

Comment: I need help in C# to do the redirection in a From to this 'javascript:Goto(DM_NEW_OBJECT.ASPX?DM_CAT_ID=2171&amp;DM_PARENT_ID=254769&amp;INPUTSELECTION=&amp;DM_OBJECT_ID=0&amp;PACK_ID=0&amp;CASE_ID=0&amp;mode=0&amp;SITE=Default);' and the control is a element of list when you click you are redirected in a new page

Comment: yes, that i got, my question would rather be if you could specify which components you are using, which outlook you are designing for and what javascript, html and asp.net tags have to do with an Outlook-Addin? Furthermore, there is no base url specified in your javascript link, so there is no way to know to which server one needs to go. You are asking the question, how about specifying as much as you can, so we don't have to ask...

Comment: In C# I have a From. In my Form I added a WebBrowser. I load a url with the method `WebBrowser.Navigate("myUrl")`. Now I want to redirect automatically with the javascript call. My question is : Is possible to launch this javascript in C# and how ? Or I must to ask my application "to press" the button (but for that I need to retrieve the button) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attach yourself to the DocumentCompleted event, it triggers when the document is fully loaded and then you can search the DOM in a similar way.

First you add an event handler to your DocumentCompleted event inside your Constructor, and remove your event handler when the Form closes.

On the load event, you can navigate to the wanted page, and then search the DOM for all li's, and then check for the text you want. If it matches, search for the URL's and then invoke the click event (which would trigger your javascript Goto function).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += OnPageCompleted;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "DemoPage.html"));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPageCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (webBrowser1.Document == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (webBrowser1.Document.Body == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        HtmlElementCollection col = webBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("li");
        if (col == null || col.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (HtmlElement elem in col)
        {
            if (elem == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(elem.InnerHtml))
            {
                continue;
            }
            var links = elem.GetElementsByTagName("a");
            if (links == null || links.Count == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            foreach (HtmlElement url in links)
            {
                if (url == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url.InnerHtml))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                try
                {
                    url.InvokeMember("click");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType().FullName + "\r\n" + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= OnPageCompleted;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. It didn't work I don't know why. I debug hem and he don't step in `foreach (HtmlElement htmlElem in htmlElements)`

Comment: This is the stucture for my element :`html>body>form>div>table>tbody>tr>td>div>table>tbody>tr>td>div>ul>li>div>ul>li>a>span`

Comment: I update the code to use the DocumentCompleted event rather than the Navigated event...

Comment: Thank you !!! There's still things to fix, but I think this is good way. I'll manage. thank you for your time.